# When is an open embedding of topological spaces a proper map?

Tags: general-topology

Assume that $f: X\to Y$ is an open embedding. That is, $f$ is a homeomorphism on its image $f(X)$ such that $f(X)$ is open in $Y$. Under what special condition is $f$ a proper map?
Thanks.

Comment: If your definition is that a map is proper if and only if preimages of compact sets are compact, this is really a condition on $f(X)$: it's the case if and only if, for all $K$ compact, $K\cap f(X)$ is compact.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Thorgott, we may assume that $f$ is the inclusion of an open subset $X\subseteq Y$.

I claim that if $f$ is proper, then $X$ is sequentially closed in $Y$.  Consequently, if we moreover assume that $Y$ is
first countable, e.g. metrizable, then $X$ is necessarily closed.

In order to see this, suppose by contradiction that $\{x_n\}_n$ is a sequence in $X$, converging to some point $y$ in
$Y\setminus X$.  Then
$$
  K:= \{x_n:n\in {\mathbb N}\} \cup  \{y\}
  $$
is a compact set, and hence so is
$$
  f^{-1}(K) = K\cap  X = \{x_n:n\in {\mathbb N}\}.
  $$
Since compact sets are closed (assuming $Y$ is Hausdorff), we deduce that  $\{x_n:n\in {\mathbb N}\}$ is closed and hence contain
$y$,   a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

WLOG, we can restrict to inclusions $i\colon X\subseteq Y$. If $Y$ is LCH, this inclusion is a proper map if and only if $X$ is closed in $Y$ (the assumption that $X$ is open will not be necessary for this conclusion). If $X$ is closed and $K\subseteq Y$ is compact, then $X\cap K=i^{-1}(K)$ is a closed subspace of the compact space $K$, hence compact itself. Thus, $i$ is proper. Now, assume conversely that $i$ is proper. Let $x\in\overline{X}$. Since $Y$ is locally compact, there exists a compact neighborhood $x\in K\subseteq Y$. Thus, every neighborhood of $x$ intersects both $X$ and $K$, whence $X\cap K$, i.e. $x\in\overline{X\cap K}$. However, $X\cap K=i^{-1}(K)$ is compact by assumption, hence closed since $Y$ is Hausdorff. Thus, $x\in\overline{X\cap K}=X\cap K\subseteq X$. Since $x\in\overline{X}$ was arbitrary, we conclude $\overline{X}=X$, i.e. $X$ is closed.